# Image orientation and layout in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, size

Forgive me if this sounds impossible, I am new at CSS. I want to make a <div> tag and give it a class of 'imagepanel1-2'. The point is to have 3 images in this panel: 1 large and 2 small (the 2 smalls would be stacked on each other just  the right of the large one).

And I want to be able to do this in the HTML:

```
<div class='imagepanel1-2'>
   <img class='large' src='blahblah'>
   <img class='small' src='blahblah'>
   <img class='small' src='blahblah'>
</div>
```

In the CSS the 'large' and 'small' subclasses would control the widths and heights of the images, and the 'imagepanel1-2' would control the orientation. Also, there should be 1 pixel empty space between each image in the panel. Is what I am describing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it would be doable if you use the right css for the 'small' and 'large' classes. As for orientation I'm not sure what you mean, but for the space you can set the margin of the divs.
For example you can set

```
float: left;
width: 100px;
margin: 1px;
```

for the 'large' class,

```
float: right;
width 50px;
margin: 1px;
```

for the 'small' class, and

```
width: 150px;
```

for the 'imagepanel 1-2' class. (I haven't tried out the code yet.)

Comment: You might make 'imagepanel1-2' 1px wider to accommodate the 1px margin between images... Also maybe 'large' should only have margin-right and 'small' should only have margin-bottom, otherwise there will be 2px between images.

Comment: yea some value-tweaking might be needed :)

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot guys, this will put me on the right track :)